# Using Date( strtotime()) and AM/PM

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to receive a PM from my date()but I am always getting a AM back.
I looked in our MYSQL database and the datatype is set to TIME.
I was wondering how I can fix this within PHP. IF it is a database issue, what is the best datatype so I can receive AM/PM?

Here is my code(The sun rise row is working perfectly. The Sun set row is returning a AM...)

```
            <td><?= $time= date("g:i A", strtotime("$srise_dec")) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><strong>Average Sunset</strong>
            </td>
            <td><?= $time= date("G:i A" , strtotime("$sset_jan")) ?></td>
```

Comment: Please don't pollute your question with useless lines, just a few will do. We can't help you unless you provide what your MySQL data looks like in the first place.

Comment: can you please provide an example data var_dump of $sset_jan,<td><?= $time= date("G:i A" , strtotime("$sset_jan")) ?></td>

Comment: Looks fine. As @Val said, please provide `var_dump($sset_jan)`

Comment: It is outputting " 5:45 AM " where I want it to be "5:45 
PM"... Basically I want to know is how does the A tell the difference between am or pm?

Comment: If the time is before noon it outputs `AM`, if the time is after noon it outputs `PM`.

Comment: If `$sset_jan` doesn't have AM or PM in it, it's assumed to be using 24-hour time. So if it contains `5:45`, that will be interpreted as `5:45 AM`. It should be `17:45` if you want it to become `5:45 PM`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, that solved my problem. I didn't even think of using the 24-hour time input! Thank you all for the help also!